# How to use 'fly'?

Tags: word-choice, gerunds, infinitives

> There is your sky
>   Break your cage
>   You meant for fly
>   Not for staying in a range

"You meant for flying" Or "You meant for fly"

Which one is correct?

Comment: Sounds like song lyrics, which are off-topic here.  But "You were meant for fly" is poor syntax, in the normal interpretation of "fly".

Comment: @HotLicks it is a quotation written by me, why the way thanks for helping 

Answer (score 0):

Neither is correct. It would be either "You are meant for flying" (your body is designed for flight) or "You meant to fly" (you intended to fly, but you couldn't).

However, lyrics and poetry do not necessarily follow conventional grammar...

Comment: I think the intended meaning is: *You were meant to fly*